# Reading data from .csv or .txt in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a beginner for python and TensorFlow. Following the instruction of "Reading data" in TensorFlow website, I want to load some data in to my project in python. That is my code, very simple

```
import tensorflow as tf
files = tf.train.match_filenames_once("*.txt")
print(files)
```

And the result is

```
Tensor("matching_filenames/read:0", dtype=string)
```

I have put the data which I want to read to the working space of this project. Why it still told me that matching file name is 0?

In addition, the data I want to read is a one dimensional data list, each double per line. And the file size is about 100W+ numbers.

The IDE I'm using is pycharm

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `Files` is a Tensor (a node in the TensorFlow graph). You need to run it in a TensorFlow session, in order to get access to its value.

```
files = tf.train.match_filenames_once("*.txt")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(files))
```

I would advise you to read the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started) to know more about TensorFlow, the Tensors, and the TensorFlow graph.

Comment: Thank you! Uh.. It seem that is too simple question. I have read almost all basic documentation in the official website. But not do some real programming, so... No matter what, thank you !